# Removing Extra Line From String Using regex

Tags: php, regex

My string is having text like this;

```
TEXT 1 GOES HERE

TEXT 2 GOES HERE

TEXT 3 GOES HERE
```

I want it to be like this;

```
TEXT 1 GOES HERE
TEXT 2 GOES HERE
TEXT 3 GOES HERE
```

I'm trying this code;

```
    $news_setting = str_replace('\n\n','\n',$news_settings);
    $news_array = explode("\n",$news_setting);
    foreach($news_array AS $news)
    {
        $news_bit .= '<div class="news_bit">'.$news.'</div>';
    }
```

But unfortunately its not removing any extra line break. Please help!

Comment: str_replace() is not the solution for this. You have to try preg_replace()

Comment: Hi tahnkx. Please give me any example?

Comment: OK, wait for a minute or two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $news_setting = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $news_settings);
    $news_array = explode("\n",$news_setting);
    foreach($news_array AS $news)
    {
        $news_bit .= '<div class="news_bit">'.$news.'</div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$text = "TEXT 1 GOES HERE

TEXT 2 GOES HERE

TEXT 3 GOES HERE";
$text = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $text);
echo $text;
```